# Referring to an object which has a syntax that is not allowed

Tags: javascript, function, syntax

I have a variable which looks as follows:

```
player.participant.X_real_false,false_0,1
```

The naming of this variable is created based on other objects.

```
app.naming = function() {
    return 'X_' + app.somethingA + '_' + app.somethingB + '_' + app.somethingC;
}
```

I can put anything in between and change the order of the elements of the name, but I cannot change the elements which make up the naming.

How can I refer to this variable in Javascript?

Comment: is it a variable or key of an object? cannot be a variable.

Comment: I think it might be a key of an object. Sorry, really new to Javascript.

Comment: player.participant['X_real_false,false_0,1'] or  player.participant[app.naming] should do. not sure how and where you are using app.naming

Comment: Thank you. How do I add the `'` to app.naming? I mean the brackets I can add with `'['`, but how do I do it for the `'` ?

Comment: why you want to add ' with app.naming? seems we are not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: I am using an application made by someone else. It names a lot of different variables automatically based on the options chosen. So I do not really have a lot of choice.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {}

obj["any-name-with-any-$@%&-chars"] = 1;

console.log(obj, obj["any-name-with-any-$@%&-chars"])
```

Comment: Thank you very much AlexOwl. Could you please elaborate a little bit on what the code does exactly (and how to apply it to my question)? I am not very proficient with Javascript..

Comment: @Tom create an object where you will store you data, you can create key with any chars and then refer to it